# Get values of Generic argument extending array

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Is it possible to retrieve the values of a generic type that extends, e.g., `string[]`? My use case is to check whether a given value is included in this "array":

```ts
function isC<C extends string[]>(attribute: string): attribute is C[number] {
  const valueSet: Set<string> = new Set(C)
  return valueSet.has(attribute)
}
```

Comment: TS compiles more or less as-is to JS; it merely removes the static types (unless you need downleveling).  So this compiles to `function isC(attribute) { const valueSet = new Set(C); return valueSet.has(attribute) }`.  There's no `C` at runtime, so this fails.  If you need to search an array, you need an actual array (not an "array").  Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WY46Qm) maybe, or more plausibly [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnK1Bm).  If that fully addresses your question I can write up an answer explaining. Otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Yep thanks, I could refactor to use a private function to fill the logic from the function with the needed class attributes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript, and the JavaScript is what actually runs.  Your function therefore compiles to

```
function isC(attribute) {
    const valueSet = new Set(C); // <-- this C doesn't exist
    return valueSet.has(attribute);
}
```

And that's the problem the compiler is warning you about.  There is no such thing as `C` in your JavaScript code.  `C` is just a *type*, and that type is not present at runtime.  In order for this to make any sense at runtime, you need to have a *value* of type `C`.  Possibly like this:

```
function isC<C extends string[]>(attributes: [...C], attribute: string): attribute is C[number] {
    const valueSet: Set<string> = new Set(attributes)
    return valueSet.has(attribute)
}
```

And that will work:

```
let attr = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "b" : "d";
if (isC(["a", "b", "c"], attr)) {
    console.log({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }[attr]);
} else {
    console.log("nope");
}
```

Note, though, that the particular implementation can probably be tweaked.  There's no reason why you need to keep track of the actual array type, you just want the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the elements.  And putting all elements from the array into a `Set` and then doing a `has()` is overkill, since you can stop inspecting the array as soon as you find the element in question.  Therefore I'd suggest:

```
function isC<C extends string>(cArray: C[], attribute: string): attribute is C {
    return (cArray as readonly string[]).includes(attribute);
}
```

Which also works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=6&pln=7&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA5A9gFwOpoE4GsBLYAcyQG8AoJGpAMwFdh4NC1glCoBhAHm6QQAHhgjAAJlCRQMuYiQDaAXQB8AChAZZhAEYNRALmnbSASiObte0ZyncFwBmB0RcSitVpf47GUgBuIAA2DBAAyhAYRhEYvDJypCpIALxIwBAA7kgxatymnl40uJEMuByBIeGRAHQAFiBQGlpy1hD5XgC+lF2UoJCwCMg4BPIAEq7IVAX0TCxsHFx8AsKiElLx8srqli360EYK1UfcSgA0SDu6e0YbZhbNVzZcSPaOzq7uVIW0PsB+FaEYtFInETCQkql0lkcpdWlB2t8kMUMKVysFATV6o1YXsETQel4gpELs0UkgALKaWrVXAgCRoMBqUxIXhIAAM1QArEgAPxIABEOn5SCM-PE-IA3NNCHQkGpFmoFPyQPzzoLVQL4PyziTZKZmV9Eb8oGgidUgmgSGpyBcjABGc46IwAJnO8CMAGYkB0FDslKYpZ1BEEoJNpt5fKaIObLWp+cA0DAIPyA9Muj0+tA4IgkAAhSKiXAASTAMCCHi8jGYrHYtiWghEYkkxgS4LU8AAgrhaQBPIz2HU4wwt+TmXW7J52CuI5GouWd7sgHsXKTFEDidhBZe3RT+6rEeAhcTQJpWXGB2gE2hEjDjsmUjDU2n0xnM1kc7l89UigXiqXS2V5R4RVlQ1dU1S1Qdmn1advmNKMYytG0QHtR0XTdT1vV9ZolGqDA0AAMUIIQIHEJlUyDCAQzDREkHgs0LSteNE2TCjL26IA)